# Probability related to record index that cross zeros in $[0, 1, \cdots, N]^{\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, st.statistics

This question is inspired by this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.02095). For those who are interested in more details and applications about record index and record values, you can find them in the paper.

Let $X=\{0, 1, 2, \cdots, N\}$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ ($N>1$) and $p$ be a non-uniform distribution on $X$ such that for each $0\leq i \leq N$, $p(i)=\lambda_i\in(0, 1)$. Then consider the probability space $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ equipped with the $\sigma$-algebra generated by finite cylinder sets and the product probability measure $\bigotimes_{n\in\mathbb{N}}p$. For my convenience given any $i, j\in\mathbb{N}$ I use $[i, j]$ to denote the set $\{i, i+1, \cdots, j\}$ if $i\leq j$; when $i>j$, $[i, j] = \emptyset$. Fix $n\in X\backslash \{0\}$ and $\{s_i\}_{1\leq i \leq n}$ an increasing finite subsequence of $X\backslash\{0\}$. Then define the following new notation:

> Given $x = (x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \in X^{\mathbb{N}}$, whenever there exists an increasing finite set $\{j_i\}_{1\leq i \leq n}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_{j_1} = s_1, x_{j_2} = s_2, \cdots, x_{j_n} = s_n$, we say $(s_i)_{1\leq i \leq n} \subseteq x$. In this case we call $\{j_i\}_{1\leq i \leq n}$ the **record index** of $x$. When $(s_i)_{1\leq i \leq n} \subseteq x$, we further say **$x$ contains zeros** if there exists $1\leq i < n$ and $l\in \{x_{j_i+1}, x_{j_i+2}, \cdots, x_{j_{i+1}-1}\}$ such that $x_l=0$. When $(n_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}\subseteq x$ and $x$ contains zeros, we use $o(x)$ to denote the index $l$ such that $x_l=0$.

Let $S$ denote the set of all $x\in X^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $(s_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}\subseteq x$ and $x$ contains zeros. Next define:

> Suppose $x\in S$. Let $\{j_i\}_{1\leq i \leq n}$ be the record index of $x$. In this case we say $\{j_i\}_{1\leq i \leq n}$ **cross the zeros of $x$** if given any $l\in o(x)$, if $l\in [j_i+1, \cdots, j_{i+1}-1]$ for some $1\leq i < n$, then $$\large \max\{ x_{j_i+1}, x_{j_i+2}, \cdots, x_{l-1}\}\leq s_i$$

Now what is the measure of $S$ and its subset $\big\{ x\in S: \text{the record index of }\, x\, \text{ cross zeros of  }\, x\big\}$?